# How do i replace a single number (from a set of lines) from a list of numbers?

Tags: python

i am new to databases and i would like to do this in my database.
Should i use word 2007 or Python or something else? i have only those two things currently.

original message is this:
hello how are you ref=13515
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior

this message has a number which is to be replaced by a number in this list

876191
11166524
1117225
1116953
798993
793519
1116737
1116691
1116364
1115635
909014
760195
689981
604787
1116217
1104482
869990
886290
1115893

and the message should copypaste itself that number of times as there are
 numbers in that list.

so my result should be

hello how are you ref=876191
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=11166524
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=1117225
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
and so on

pls note that the numbers in the list are 6 or 7 or 8 digit numbers

thank you

Answer (score 1):

it is an interesting question and it can be done inside sql server.

first I put the original message into a table - @messages_original.
there was no need for it to be a table, since there is only one.

```
    set nocount on

    declare @messages_original table ( i int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered, mess varchar(1008) not null)

    declare @results table ( i int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered, mess varchar(1008) not null)

    declare @numbers table ( i int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered, num varchar(10) not null)

    declare @i int 
    declare @z int
    declare @number_ varchar(10) --- the number in the original message
    declare @number  varchar(10) --- the number that needs to be replace the original number and save to the @results

    insert into @messages_original values ('hello how are you ref=13515
    ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
    ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
    nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior')

     --I add the numbers into another table.

    insert into @numbers (num) values ('876191')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('11166524')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1117225')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1116953')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('798993')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('793519')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1116737')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1116691')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1116364')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1115635')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('909014')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('760195')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('689981')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('604787')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1116217')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1104482')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('869990')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('886290')
    insert into @numbers (num) values ('1115893')

select @i = 1,
       @z = count(*) from @numbers 

select @number_ =  SubString(mess,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',mess),Len(mess)),
       @number_ =  SubString(@number_,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@number_))
from
@messages_original 
where i = 1


while (@i <= @z) begin

        select @number = num from @numbers where i = @i

        insert into @results(mess)
        select replace(mess,@number_,@number)
        from
        @messages_original 
        where i = 1



select @i = @i+ 1

end /*while*/


select * from @results
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was quite lost.

Comment: Krishna, instead of writing "thank you", if the answer was helpful, you upvote it, or accept it, or both. Otherwise, it is ok. I will leave it here, because hopefully it will help someone, and for me it was a cool exercise in sql. thank you for your question.

Comment: you asked in python, I replied in sql, it was my fault really.